# Tomato wilt identification

Tags: tomatoes, wilt

I'm growing tomatoes in a raised bed. I planted four different varieties; one of them, Brandywine, has wilted pretty aggressively on one side of the plant (pictures below). I have a number of other tomatoes in the plot which look fine, but I'm concerned that if there's a disease it could spread to the other plants. I don't have much experience growing tomatoes so I would appreciate any help in identifying what the problem might be.

We water the tomatoes and peppers most days that it doesn’t rain. I planted them maybe a month ago, and fertilized once with Tomato-tone. I am located in hardness zone 7A.

Thanks!

Photos:

The entire plant (in the silver cage), surrounded by some pepper plants.
[image: The entire plant (in the silver cage), surrounded by some pepper plants.]

Another view of the wilted leaves.
[image: Another view of the wilted leaves.]

Some of the leaves starting to turn yellow.
[image: Some of the leaves starting to turn yellow.]

A close up of some wilted leaves.
[image: A close up of some wilted leaves.]